# how can I activate virtual environment in python shell

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment (directory is **env**) and have installed some third party packages. I work with Mac OSX. How can I **activate my venv** in the **python interactive shell**? I tried

```
source env/bin/activate
```

and get the error message: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I have seen some had posted this question 8 years ago but I haven't found what I was looking for...I have also checked the python documentation but it is not clear for me how to activate it

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html?highlight=virtual

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Please provide full error you're getting

Comment: You don't activate the virtual environment *in the Python shell*. You do so before opening the Python shell. In other words, you run that command in your *system's shell*.

Comment: I read the question wrong :). Sorry, you do `source /path/to/activate` in the `SHELL` you are using, not inside the interactive `python` interpreter :). `source` is a shell(bash, ksh...) bultin function :) and `not` a `python` related stuff

Comment: Thanks, malberts. So I have to use the Terminal on my Mac, correct? Then, my second question is: do I have to start IDLE in the Terminal of my system?

Comment: thanks @han solo: so, when I am used to work with IDLE, what is the right procedure? First activate env in the system's terminal...and then?

Comment: When you `activate` a virtualenv, you are changing which python executable the shell is running. For this reason, you cannot activate a virtualenv while python is running, because you've already selected a specific interpreter

Comment: thanks @C.Nivs. So, what would be a correct work flow to run programs in a virtualenv in IDLE on a MAC? Can you please provide a step by step instruction? Do I have to run them in the terminal? Meaning that I cannot use IDLE when I am in virtualenv?

Answer (score 2):

In your shell, normally `python` will point you to a default instance of python:

```sh
python

Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 25 2017, 09:53:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

This is because `python` is located in `/usr/local/bin` which is part of your default `PATH`. Now, when you `source activate <some_env>`, you are *modifying* `PATH`, which you can actually see in the `/path/to/venv/some_env/bin/activate` file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

...

    if [[ $PATH == *"CONDA_PATH_PLACEHOLDER"* ]]; then
        # If it did, replace it with our _NEW_PART
        export PATH="$($_CONDA_PYTHON -c "import re; print(re.sub(r'CONDA_PATH_PLACEHOLDER', r'$_NEW_PART', '$PATH', 1))")"
    else

        #### HERE IS WHERE THAT PATH IS OVERWRITTEN

        export PATH="$_NEW_PART:$PATH"
    fi

    # CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV is the shortest representation of how conda recognizes your env.
    #    It can be an env name, or a full path.
    #    Last date of change: 2016-06-21
    # If the string contains / it's a path
    if [[ "$@" == */* ]]; then
        export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=$(get_abs_filename "$args")
    else
        export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV="$args"
    fi
...
esac
```

I'm using anaconda but the concept is the same, and `...` indicates where I've snipped out parts of the script. It is effectively exporting the venv `python` executable path into `PATH`. So you won't be pointing to your `venv` python unless one of two conditions arises: a) you explicitly call that python executable or b) you `source activate myenv` and *then* call `python`.

So the correct workflow is:

`source /path/to/myenv/bin/activate myenv`

Then call
`python`

As an example, the first call to `$PATH` is *before* activating my conda env, the second is after:

```sh
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/Users/mm92400/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/bin:/Users/mm92400/.cargo/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
➜  ~ source activate py36
(py36) ➜  ~ echo $PATH
/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin:/Users/mm92400/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/bin:/Users/mm92400/.cargo/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

note how `$PATH` is different

Comment: Thanks @C.Nivs. I have problems with the source code to activate my virtualenv. When I type in the code that you have indicated I get an error message: No such file or directory.

Comment: What explicitly are you giving when trying to activate your virtualenv?

Comment: @ C.Nives. I typed in exactly what you have written: source /path/to/myenv/bin/activate myenv

Comment: Ok that's a sample path. It depends on where you've installed your virtualenv. You will need to adjust that as necessary. For example, on my machine that would be `~/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/activate`

Comment: @ C.Nives: Sorry, I am not familiar with the Terminal and a beginner in Coding, so thanks for your patience. The path of my virtualenv folder is as follows: Macintosh HD -> User -> Andrea -> env. What do I have to type into the Terminal?

Comment: @ C.Nives: My last line in the Terminal looks as follows before I type in something: (base) imacAM:~ Andrea$

Comment: cool. so you will want to type `source ~/env/bin/activate`. The `~` is short for `HOME` which in your case will be `/Users/Andrea`

Comment: @ C.Nivs: ok thanks. So now I know how to activate the virtualenv. What about the second step, calling python? What do you mean exactly by calling python? I have found some code on stackoverflow which seems reasonable to open IDLE but after a while there is a block of code which says that I cannot run python in two different locations. Or something with that meaning.

Comment: once you `source activate` a virutalenv, entering `python` in the terminal will point you to the `python` interpreter that is tied to that virutalenv. So you can call scripts like you would normally

Comment: @ C.Nivs: Thanks. I can activate my virutalenv and can open IDLE from the Terminal. The thing is, when I run a program from my virtualenv in IDLE, I get the following message in my Terminal: objc [14076]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/AFinderKit (0x7fffa9866210) and /System/Library PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x10fd32dc8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: @ When this message appears, I cannot deactivate my virtualenv in the Terminal anymore. I can only close the Terminal window...

Comment: That sounds like a new SO question. If I were to guess, your virtualenv *might* be leveraging the interpreter that comes with Mac

Comment: @ C.Nivs: What do you mean exactly by "leveraging" the interpreter?

Comment: @aurumpurum what code are you running in IDLE? Some googling suggests you could be running `Tkinter`

Comment: @ C.Nivs: for example: 1) I activate my virtual environment 2) the prompt changes from (base) to (env) (base) which is correct. 3) then I open idle from the Terminal: I just type idle in and the Idle window pops up. In Idle I open the file that I saved in my virtual environment folder. 4) Then I run the following code: import requests


r = requests.get("http://google.com")
print(r.content)